# pyspark regex string matching

Tags: regex, dataframe, pyspark

I have a strings in a dataframe in the following format.

```
abc.T01.xyz
abc.def.T01.xyz
abc.def.ghi.xyz
```

I need to filter the rows where this string has values matching this expression.

```
[a-zA-Z].T[0-9].[a-zA-Z]
```

I have used the following command, but it is giving me the strings that look like this as well: `[a-zA-Z].[a-zA-Z].T[0-9].[a-zA-Z]` which I don't want in my result.

```
mydf2 = mydf1.where('col1 rlike ".*\.T.*\..*"')
mydf2.show()
```

I am missing something in my regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just translate your requirements instead of using a dot-star-soup and add anchors:

```
# [a-zA-Z].T[0-9].[a-zA-Z]
mydf2 = mydf1.where('col1 rlike "^[a-zA-Z.]+\.T[0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z.]+$"')
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/9I4V0j/1/).
*Please note, that I have also added the dot to the character class (is this a requirement?), otherwise your second string won't be matched. If this is not what you want, delete it from the class.*